# When I press F12 my render looks distorted

Tags: rendering, image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH3JY.jpg

this is what it looks like. I have no clue why :D this is my second ever creation.

Comment: Do you have any objects hidden in your viewport? Hidden objects will still appear in renders.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett there isn't anything hidden.